# Good and inexpensive mouse

Tags: mice, programmable

I noticed that my mouse sometimes interrupts clicking and holding of the left mouse button, and sometimes sends a double click even if I didn't. Now it's probably the right time to buy a new mouse.

Requierments:

- not expensive (max price about 40 to 50€; the less the better)
- Has to be suitable for some occasional gaming (meaning it should be a classical mouse and not a track pad or similar)
- Non-Wireless, because there is no need for position changing (only if it's a really amazing mouse)
- A mouse that is able to operate on a plastic mouse pad (preferable) or a wooden table.

Ideally:

- some macro buttons would be cool
- Buyable in the EU (living in the EU it's easier in terms of taxes etc.)
- Ergonomic

Additional info:

- I use my mouse with the right hand
- As long as it is not a mouse with a ball for the positioning (like in old mouses) I don't care about optical, laser etc.

**EDIT:**

Even when this thread is already 2 months old I still did not buy any mouse, and still need one.

Comment: Laser is typically better for hard surfaces. Don't trust optical mice without explicit proof that they work on hard surfaces.

Comment: Suddenly, lots of Logitech gaming mice are on sale today. Bought my own for a full price, thinking about an extra one ) But they are no cheaper than $30.

Comment: I got a HP 240 bluetooth mouse (https://www.hp.com/us-en/shop/pdp/hp-240-black-bluetooth-mouse) which has proven simple enough for my needs.   No macro buttons though.

Answer (score 10):

I had good experience with "gaming" mouse from Logitech. Current corded lineup seems pretty narrow, MX500 appears to correspond to what I had.

Pros: it's quite wide which is good for hands; Cons: paying $30 for a mouse nowadays seems excessive.

I once bought a Microsoft mouse for a friend of mine who did computer graphics, which is just as demanding as gaming. Surprisingly Microsoft makes (or buys OEM) very good peripherals! 4500 (wired) and 900 (wireless) seem like decent models.

You can also consider low-end Razer.

Please visit a real brick and mortar store and at least try holding a mouse before you buy.

Answer (score 8):

I use the [HP BR376AA 5-Button Optical Comfort Mouse](http://store.hp.com/UKStore/Merch/Product.aspx?id=BR376AA&opt=ABB&sel=ACC). Which is a bit of a mouthful.

- It's £13.20 (17,97€, $20.36)
- It's high-precision, works very well for gaming (I use it to play games quite a lot)
- Wired

Additionally...

- It has 2 side buttons which are normally mapped to browser back/forward. You might be able to assign macros to them - I haven't researched this, but it seems viable.
- I got mine in the UK which is (sort of) in the EU. It's probably purchasable in mainland Europe, too.
- "Comfort" in HP speak means ergonomic. It's very nice to use.

Answer (score 6):

I use the Etekcity Scroll X1. It costs $15. It has 4 extra buttons (2 Side Buttons and 2 more behind the mouse wheel) It fits perfectly in my hand (I use the fingertip grip, i.e. I only touch the mouse with the tips of my fingers and the bottom of the palm of my hand) It includes drivers, and it's very cheap. It is 2400 DPI, but for 18 dollars you can get a 4000 DPI Model and $26 will buy you a 8200 DPI Mouse -- which is just insane. You can see more info and buy it [here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00F3L19KQ).

Answer (score 5):

Try some mice out at a local store, thats the best way to see if they fit in your hand and feel good and ergonomic for you.

And a real ergonomic mouse to prevent tennis elbow is something like this: [CSL - TM137U optical sensor](http://www.amazon.de/CSL-Ausf%C3%BChrung-ergonomisches-Vorbeugung-armschonend/dp/B00HNAQA72/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1442113401&sr=8-1&keywords=maus%20ergonomisch/) but i don't know if you want to use one of this kind. I think it would take some time to get used to it but health wise this shape is the best choice.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming your plastic mouse pad is a good, solid color, the [Logitech M500](http://www.newegg.com/global/nl/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16826104328) (€27) is a fantastic laser mouse for the price. It's built for everyday use but can withstand occasional gaming. It's wired, ergonomically right-handed, has side macros, and 1000 DPI (which is more than enough for gaming).

One thing you should take caution to is the track type. For your purposes, laser mice are better since you have hard surfaces. Optical mice work well with soft surfaces.

Answer (score 5):

The [Logitech G502](http://gaming.logitech.com/en-us/product/g502-proteus-spectrum-rgb-gaming-mouse) would be great for your purpose. It has multiple macro buttons and all the buttons are programmable through software. The mouse is ergonomic and is a great gaming mouse. It is also not very expensive for what it is.

[image]

Comment: But 90€ is a bit expensive. Even though it's on sale for 60€ on amazon.de it's a bit much. 50€ is the absolute limit. Although only if it's really good.

Answer (score 4):

I would go with the HAVIT® HV-MS672 Ergonomic LED Stress-ease Wired Mouse
from Amazon.

$10 (+)
Normal mouse (+)
Wired (+)
Great for mousepads (smooth back surface) (+)
Ergonomic (according to HAVIT ) (+)

Some bonuses:
6 led lights (warning: 
cannot change to specific color )  (+)
Back/foward button (+) 
DPI button (ideal for gaming with 4 options) (+)

I'm ordering this mouse tomorrow so I may update soon.

Answer (score 4):

## [Roccat Lua](http://www.roccat.org/en-US/Products/Gaming-Mice/Lua/)

- Cost: 20$ on Amazon.com
- 2000dpi optical Sensor
- 60 ips maximum speed
- 20G acceleration
- 1000Hz polling rate
- 1.8m USB cable
- No-sweat side grips
- 2D scroll wheel

I'm actually using this mice and if you are looking for standard 3 button + scroll wheel mouse which is good for gaming, Roccat Lua is really good choice.

Answer (score 3):

**Logitech MX master**

A really nice mouse that is made out of solid metal with a gold and black look. On the left side it has 3 buttons, with one featuring a gesture control. It means that you can do gestures for Windows and custom ones by holding that button. That button is also the thumb rest. Just right above that is a horizontal scrolling wheel and 2 macro buttons.

The scroll wheel can tilt to the left and right and features a smart lock system. It means that when you scroll fast it will unlock and use free scroll. Sensitivity can be changed in software. It also has an unlock button for free scroll.

The software is nice and simple to use with a friendly UI. It isn't wired though.

This mouse cost more than your budget but it is totally worth it.
It's 80 to 100 Euros.

Answer (score 2):

**Trust GXT31 USB**
This is from trust wich is a buget computer tech company. This is a smal low profile style mouse. it has 1 LED that can change colour in software. it has 2 macro buttons on the left side of the mouse. had has a button on the top. it has a smooth scrolling scroll wheel but is not analog or free scrolling. it has a rubber texture on the left side of the mouse and a smooth finish on the top sporting a cammo look. it has a infra red sensor.

The software is not bad and easy to use.

This mouse is around 20 euro if you can find it

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the Razer Deathadder. It is slightly expensive ($60) but it has a very comfy design, a well built software with 2 fully programmable macro buttons and a strong build quality. This is the mouse I'm using right now as my gaming gear. There is also cool looking green backlight.

Comment: Bit short. Can you elaborate and maybe say how one might procure the Deathadder in the EU (maybe using an Amazon link)

Answer (score 1):

**Trust GXT 166 MMO**
This is a razer naga style mouse. it has a high grip and 11 buttons on the left side of the mouse. this mouse doesn't have a thump rest but that isnt that bad. it glides okey but not the best. it has a red and black color sceme. has a okey scrolling wheel. it has a weight system and is ofset to the left for a pink rest. it is wired with a red cable it has lights in the scroll wheel and the logo. it also has 2 buttons below the scroll wheel.

Answer (score 0):

The best mouse that I have ever bought, in fact the only mouse that I have ever bought (as I usually get mine from corporate throw outs), was a mouse made by NUBWO. It is a [Nubwo Phelan NM-18](http://www.nubwo.com/gaming-mouse/phelan/):

[image: Nubwo Phelan]

Now I purchased this is Thailand, so I am not sure if they are widely available in the West, although they *are* designed in the USA. It cost me B$180, or $4, and it was not a copy or clone. It is a beautiful looking thing, and very comfortable to hold. It also has a plethora (well, a couple) of side buttons, which worked well (i.e. they weren't ignored) on an OS X machine (I have never used the mouse on a WinTel machine).

It also has a small resolution button that can cycle through four different pre-set speeds, 400, 800, 1600 and 2400 DPI, which I found to be very useful (when drawing technical designs), after having initially scoffed at it.

In addition, it has a colourful light display in the top, which looks cool, although it could be distracting, if working with the lights out.

Comment: It looks like it isn't available outside of Thailand. Importing it is possible, but shipping and taxes could cost a lot, which makes it an expensive mouse (according to DHL 1kg package from Thailand to Germany 2000 THB or 52 EUR, which probably(!) includes taxes)

Comment: @szoszk - Yes, the postage would make it not worthwhile. That is a shame. Maybe I should bring some back to Europe in July? :)

Answer (score 0):

I use a MadCatz R.A.T.7.   It's ergonomic, customizable, max of 6400dpi.
I use it for everything, and only had to replace it recently after the old one got flaky after six years of heavy use...and some rough treatment when moving place to place.

[RAT 7](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0095D1CM8)

I don't work for amazon or madcatz...

Answer (score 0):

### [Steelseries Rival 100](https://steelseries.com/gaming-mice/rival-100)

[image]

Costs around 40$ so not the cheapest but sa far as I'm concerned it really is a great mouse :

- Nice and sober design ; exists in different colors so you can pick you favourite
- RGB lighting
- Side "back and forward" (default, but mappable to macros) buttons
- Made of a soft matter that feels very comfortable in hand (as for the black and yellow version I am using, and the full black one)
- Wired
- Ambidextrous
- Button to switch DPI
- Is fully editable (macros, colors, button roles, DPI modes, angle correction) through Steelseries Engine software, which is amazing (in comparison with, for instace, Razer Synapse)
- Is still comfortable to use even after hours of playing

I bought it three months ago and I am a big fan of it. Plus I got a free mousepad from Steelseries for my purchase, and the two work perfectly well together.

Answer (score 0):

### Logitech G305 Lightspeed Wireless Gaming Mouse

[Logitech G305](https://www.logitechg.com/en-roeu/products/gaming-mice/g305-lightspeed-wireless-gaming-mouse.html) (sometimes referred to as G304) is an excellent performer. It comes with the top tier HERO optical sensor providing precise tracking. It is wireless which allows for greater freedom of movement. The mouse shares features with Logitech's more high-end models. It is a no-hassle mouse with great capabilities, which often receive great scores in reviews [(The Wirecutter, 2019)](https://thewirecutter.com/reviews/best-wireless-gaming-mouse/).

The mouse is also reasonably priced, and can usually be found within $40-50.

> - 1 ms low latency wireless.
> - Six buttons.
> - 250 hours battery life (swappable AA batteries).
> - 200-12000 DPI.
> - 125 / 250 / 500 / 1000 polling rate [HZ].
> - Budget-friendly.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My favorite mouse is the Action gaming mouse, although its not programmable. If you want a "macro king mouse" (LTT reference), the Logitech G300 is a good option.

Answer (score 0):

[WHITE SHARK MIYAMOTO](https://whiteshark.gg/mice/miyamoto) is the best mouse for 2D and 3D design on the market - even much more expensive competitors don't have programmable buttons below and above the thumb and that's the best thing about this mouse! It would be perfect if it had an extra button for the index finger (beside the wheel). In terms of ergonomics, it's perfect for my hand, but for smaller hands and fatter fingers I'm not shure... A slightly smaller version should be made for smaller hands.

I used to use the DELUXE M910 WIRED (wireless version does not have the possibility of programmable keys) but unfortunately it is no longer available on the market. However, the additional index finger button on this model is unusable as it is in the wrong place.

The Logitech G502 has solid ergonomics and practical buttons, but I returned it because the software is unacceptably robust to me...

I spend a lot of time working with 2D and 3D programs and the mouse is a VERY important tool for me, I have tested many different models and I can tell you that the buttons below and above the thumb, although it may not look like it, are the most pleasant and useful of all that I have tried. .. I hope that many more similar mice will appear on the market.

P.S.
I don't play games and I guess this button layout is not convenient for that purpose.

[image: WHITE SHARK MIYAMOTO]